# Amcharts Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

I have found this angular directive 
[Directive](https://github.com/connecta-solutions/angular-amchart/blob/master/angular-amchart/amchart.js)

but when i create two identical charts It crashes, and I can not add charts.

The problem is that the Directive, generate random id .

Is there a way to write directly in the scope?

Thank you!

UPDATE(1)

I have an array of chart :
for example

```
$scope.charts = [
{
    name:"Simple Pie Chart",
    image:"/theme2/assets/img/widget2.png",
    "struct":{
        "type": "pie",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
        "titleField": "category",
        "valueField": "column-1",
        "allLabels": [],
        "balloon": {},
        "titles": [],
        "data": [
            {
                "category": "category 1",
                "column-1": 8
            },
            {
                "category": "category 2",
                "column-1": 6
            },
            {
                "category": "category 3",
                "column-1": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When user select one of this charts  I add it in a variable->

```
$scope.items.push(data.item); //chart selected
```

and then in the html i display the selected charts with the
[Directive](https://github.com/connecta-solutions/angular-amchart/blob/master/angular-amchart/amchart.js) :

```
 <div ng-repeat="graph in items">
                 <amchart  ng-model="graph" >
                </amchart>

            </div>
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: see the question , thank you!

Comment: i guess the ng-repeat is crashing because of duplicate items...not the chart...any working demo or fiddle?

Comment: can you try ng-repeat="graph in items track by $index"

Comment: @gaurav5430 it worked! thank you! If you answer the question, I approve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess the `ng-repeat` is crashing because of duplicate items...not the chart

try `ng-repeat="graph in items track by $index"`

this will allow you to have duplicate objects in your repeater.